# AWK 3.1.7 - multiple loops in a single for

Tags: awk, gawk

I am trying to sort 2 arrays with the following code:

```
 n = asorti (pacben,pacsor)
 m = asorti (pacben2,pacsor2)
```

I need to sort them, preferable together. I know that I can do each separately with the following:

```
 n = asorti (pacben,pacsor)
for (p = 1;p <= n; p++) {
blah
}
 m = asorti (pacben2,pacsor2)
for (p2 =1;p2 <= m; p2++) {
blah
}
```

but when I try the following:

```
 n = asorti (pacben,pacsor)
 m = asorti (pacben2,pacsor2)
for (p = 1;p <= n;p++ && p2 = 1;p2 <= m;p2++) {
blah
}
```

I get the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:25:                         for (p = 1;p <= n;p++ && p2 = 1;p2 <= m; p2++) {
awk: cmd. line:25:                                                        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:25:                         for (p = 1;p <= n;p++ && p2 = 1;p2 <= m; p2++) {
awk: cmd. line:25:                                                                      ^ syntax error
```

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understood the question. The call to asorti is enough to do the sorting. The loop is to display or use the content. If you want to go through both array together you can use only one index (loose p2) and be careful that one index may be less than the other.

Comment: @callmeSteve so how would the `for` loop be written? would I have to use the same veriable for both `asorti`? eg. `n=asorti(pacben,pacsor) n=asorti(pacben2,pacsor2) for (p=1;p<=n;p++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, you'd modify:

```
for (p = 1;p <= n;p++ && p2 = 1;p2 <= m;p2++) {
```

into:

```
for (p = 1, p2 = 1; p <= n && p2 <= m; p1++, p2++) {
```

This is one of the standard uses for the comma operator.  However, it appears that `awk` does not accept the comma operator.

Mac OS X (BSD) `awk`:

```
$ awk -v n=2 -v m=3 'BEGIN { for (p = 1, p2 = 1; p <= n && p2 <= m; p1++, p2++) print p1, p2}'
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    BEGIN { for (p = >>>  1, <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
$
```

GNU `awk`:

```
$ awk -v n=2 -v m=3 'BEGIN { for (p = 1, p2 = 1; p <= n && p2 <= m; p1++, p2++) print p1, p2}'
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN { for (p = 1, p2 = 1; p <= n && p2 <= m; p1++, p2++) print p1, p2}
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN { for (p = 1, p2 = 1; p <= n && p2 <= m; p1++, p2++) print p1, p2}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                    ^ syntax error
$
```

The POSIX specification for [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02) does not include a comma operator in the list of operators.

You can use:

```
$ awk -v n=2 -v m=3 'BEGIN { for (p1 = p2 = 1; p1 <= n && p2 <= m; p1++ && p2++) print p1, p2}'
1 1
2 2
$
```

This exploits the fact that `p1` and `p2` are initialized to the same value, and that both `p1` and `p2` are non-zero in the increment portion of the loop.

Comment: Awesome thanks that works like a charm. would never of thought that you could do that in a `for` statement.

Comment: Hang on - you'd NEVER really write that last loop as it's equivalent to the far simpler `for (p = 1; p <= n && p <= m; p++) print p, p`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38038530/1745001.

Comment: Yes, @EdMorton ; there would be no need for two loop control cars as written.   I'm assuming there is something in the body of the real loop that processes (increments or decrement so ready otherwise adjusts) the loop indexes separately.

Comment: I suspect the OP just thinks he needs 2 loop control vars because he has 2 arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple. There's various possible solutions depending on whatever it is you really want and what `blah` might do but based on you accepting [@JonathanLeffer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38034881/1745001), this must be what you want:

```
n = asorti (pacben,pacsor)
m = asorti (pacben2,pacsor2)
for (p = 1;p <= n && p <=m; p++) {
    blah
}
```

but also consider how to handle arrays of different sizes:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
    n = split("A C E",a)
    m = split("B D F G H",b)
    for (p=1;p<=n && p<=m;p++) {
        print a[p] ORS b[p]
    }
    for (;p <= (n > m ? n : m);p++) {
        print (n > m ? a[p] : b[p])
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

Comment: Ahh that is nice to know.